# Cannot import solution because index size too large

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am experiencing the following error for a custom entity:

"Index size exceeded the size limit of 900 bytes. The key is too large. Try removing some columns or making the strings in string columns shorter."

I looked at the key and it previously had a max length of 300. I reduced it to 20 since it is a Phone Number entity, but it still fails to import with the following error above. I also increased it to 450 based on similar Dynamics questions I found online but no dice. How can I get around this error? Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Is your field a find column in the quick find view?

If yes, that's the reason. Because for find columns automatically an index is being created and there are limitations reg. the max. number of characters.

This is a limitation on sql side.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017